# Docker Build and Multi layer dll version

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I have `.Net` core Application with 2 class library(`BusinessLayer` and `DataLayer`).
When I want create a docker image I get below erros:

> Errors in /app/project.json
>       unable to resolve 'BusinessLayer ( >= 1.0.0)' for .NETCoreApp,version=v1.0'
>       unable to resolve 'DataLayer( >= 1.0.0)' for .NETCoreApp,version=v1.0'

The command `dotnet restore` returned a non-zero code:1
  what is the solution?
[image]

docker
[image]

Comment: We'd need to see more than just this. What does project.json look like? How are your build dependencies etc

Comment: i did no special task for dependencies.

Comment: should i do for dependensies?

Comment: Please don't post code in screenshots. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.